# Writing into CSV file: opencsv 2.3

Tags: java, csv, filewriter, opencsv

I am using opencsv 2.3 for writing into CSV file.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("data/output.csv"), '\t');

String[][] result = a.execute();

for (String[] line : result)
{
    writer.writeNext(line);   // example of line: a_1, 28
}

writer.close();
```

This code writes each line into a single cell, e.g. a_1"28".

How can I write `a_1` into the 1st column and `28` into the second column?

Update 1: I think that this code works for opencsv 3.1, hower it seems to be not working for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using tab as separator. But your line is using comma as separator.

Comment: Thanks, how would you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Oook, I had to delete , '\t'